# Running time of sort()

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

I am writing a merge sort algorithm for a list and I want to compare its running time to the method `.sort()` implemented in Python. Can anyone help me understand why my code is 10 times slower than `.sort()`? I thought that Python was using merge sort for large inputs. Maybe my code is not efficient?

My code is the following

```
def swap_left(array,key_idx):
    if key_idx>=1 and array[key_idx-1] >= array[key_idx]:
        array[key_idx-1] = array[key_idx-1] + array[key_idx]
        array[key_idx] = array[key_idx-1]- array[key_idx]
        array[key_idx-1] = array[key_idx-1] - array[key_idx]
        swap_left(array,key_idx-1)
    return array

def merge(array_left,array_right):
    key_left = 0
    key_right = 0
    sorted_list = []
    while key_left < len(array_left) and key_right < len(array_right):
        if array_left[key_left] <= array_right[key_right]:
            sorted_list.append(array_left[key_left])
            key_left+=1
        else:
            sorted_list.append(array_right[key_right])
            key_right+=1
    
    if key_left < len(array_left):
        sorted_list=sorted_list+array_left[key_left:]
    if key_right < len(array_right):
        sorted_list=sorted_list+array_right[key_right:]
    return sorted_list

    
def merge_sort(array):
    n = len(array)
    if n ==1:
        return array
    elif n==2:
        swap_left(array,1)
        return array
    else:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            key = int(n/2)-1
            merge1=merge_sort(array[:key])
            merge2=merge_sort(array[key:])
            return merge(merge1,merge2)
        else:
            key = int((n+1)/2)-1
            merge1=merge_sort(array[:key])
            merge2=merge_sort(array[key:])
            return merge(merge1,merge2)
```

and I do the comparison between my algorithm and python as

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import time
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

list_results=[]
for n in range(10,10000,50):
    array=list(np.random.randint(10000, size=n))
    start_time = time.time()
    merge_sort(array)
    end_time = time.time()
    list_results.append([n,(end_time - start_time)])

list_results2=[]
for n in range(10,10000,50):
    array=list(np.random.randint(10000, size=n))
    start_time = time.time()
    array.sort()
    end_time = time.time()
    list_results2.append([n,(end_time - start_time)])

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
list_results = np.array(list_results)
list_results2 = np.array(list_results2)
x1,y1=list_results.T
x2,y2=list_results2.T
plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.plot(x2,y2)
```

which returns [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkVaP.png)(blu points are mine running times, orange points are `.sort()`running times)

Comment: At the very least, Python's ``.sort`` is implemented in C. A pure Python implementation being just 10 times slower is actually pretty good.

Comment: Note that Python's sorting algorithm is [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), "derived from merge sort and insertion sort".

Comment: python's `List.sort` method is implemented in c, which is much faster than python. It also doesn't strictly use merge sort, but rather a more complicated ["timsort"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), though the difference is irrelevant for truly random inputs.

Comment: mCoding did an [Interesting video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybh0GttfM8o) on that topic

Comment: Note that Python allows to literally swap entries. Your ``swap_left`` should just use ``array[key_idx-1], array[key_idx] = array[key_idx], array[key_idx-1]``, which also works for non-integer values. At a glance, there are more such inefficiencies, but if you seek general input then this would be more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) – be sure to check their [question guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) first, though.